# Get relevant search results based on priority using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm fairly new to elasticsearch and would like to have Natural Language Search on my JSON format database giving priority to specific keys and getting relevant results based on the priority.

I have tried to search using Kibana but the search bar only accepts Query Language. I'm not able to convert the Natural Language Search into a Query.

Example - If the user searches for `what is income?` then `income` (should also check for substrings) must be extracted using an nlp processor and then (if priority if given to `key1` and `key2`) then it must be checked if `"key1" : "income"` or `"key2" : "income"` and if it matched then the result must be shown.

Comment: There is no built in NLP processing. To extract your priority words you'll have to run your input through an NLP processor upfront and then construct the right Elasticsearch queries based on that.

Comment: Yes, and i thinck this is not a good way to use Elastic. Why not add the field you want in your mappings and set them at indexation?